# Android: Animation scale independent animation

Tags: android, animation, scale, objectanimator

I have an animation with

```
ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(progressBar, "progress", 0, 1000);
animation.setDuration(1000);
```

The problem is, that this is not "Animation scale" independent. You can change the animation speed in the developer options. But this animation always hat to be 1 second, on every device with any settings. How can I achieve this?

Comment: you cannot do that using animator framework as it is always using those dev options

Comment: What is the alternative? There are so many apps, which have a countdown animated.

Comment: `android.os.Handler` stuff? `android.os.CountDownTimer`?

Comment: How can I make a progressbar animated with a handler? The CountDownTimer does not work, because I have to change the duration after some periods.

Comment: so use a `Handler` api: `send*MessageDelayed` / `send*MessageAtTime`

Comment: Yes but how to connect this with a progressbar? At the CountdownTimer I have the onTick where I can call .setProgress(), but how to do this with a Handler?

Comment: override handleMessage,  for more info see CountDownTimer source file